# hide divs with window.onclick --- it's complicated

Tags: javascript, popup, modal-dialog

PLEASE NOTE: this is a javascript question even though the code here is in PHP.
WARNING: long explanation coming up :-)

I have a PHP `while` loop which returns a variable number of rows from a MYSQL set. Included in each row of SQL data, there is a url for a googlemaps iframe, which is dynamically assigned to a modal popup window. The problem comes from the fact that I have to generate the javascript code to open and close each modal popup dynamically; so there is a substantial amount of javascript in the form of PHP echo (something I hate to do, but in this case, it seemed like the best option). 
Here is the code I have:

```
$sql .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where_clause); 
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $loopcount = 1; //enumerate each returned MYSQL row for popup variables

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<!--ENTRY:' . $loopcount . '-->';

            //START POPUP CODE FOR GOOGLEMAPS
                echo '<H1><span id="open_popup_' . $loopcount . '">' . $row["address"] . ',&nbsp;' . $row["city"] . '</span></H1>' . 

                '<div id="myModal_' . $loopcount . '" class="modal">' .
                    '<div class="modal-content"><iframe src="' . $row["map"] . '" width="600" height="450"></iframe></div>' . 
                    '</div>'; 

                echo '<script>
                    var modal_' . $loopcount . ' = document.getElementById(\'myModal_' . $loopcount . '\');
                    var popup_id_' . $loopcount . ' = document.getElementById("open_popup_' . $loopcount . '");

            // Open modal--THIS PART WORKS FINE
                popup_id_' . $loopcount . '.onclick = function() {
                    modal_' . $loopcount . '.style.display = "block";
                    }

            // Close modal onclick outside the modal--THIS PART DOES NOT WORK
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == modal_' . $loopcount . ') {
                        modal_' . $loopcount . '.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }
                </script>';

                $loopcount++; //INCREMENT LOOPCOUNT FOR EACH RETURNED ROW

                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
                }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

So as I mentioned in the comment, the open modal window part works perfectly because it can easily target the correct dive by id (e.g. 'modal_1', 'modal_2' etc.). However, when I click outside the window, only the LAST instance closes; any others that are there remain open and I have to reload the page to close them. I know that this is because the `event.target` will get reset with each PHP loop, and by the time the page is generated, it will only apply to the last instance.

My first thought was to put a function outside of the PHP loop which hides all divs of class `modal`, but then that would be triggered each time the user clicked anywhere on the page, and therefore, would also hide the div when the user clicks on the link to open it. So as far as I can tell, I have to keep this `function` inside my PHP loop too.

As such, I need to somehow tailor the javascript so that each generated `function(event)` will only be triggered if the associated div (by ID... 'modal_n') is shown. Beyond that, I suppose that it could simply hide all divs of class 'modal' rather than targeting the specific div which is visible (although I would prefer a method which targeted only that specific div).

I have tried my best to explain the problem clearly. As always, I would be very grateful for any help from the experts!

Comment: Why can't you put a condition to check if there are any modals available on the page, only then run the hide function.

Comment: FYI: the page in question is online HERE: http://www.s-on.ch

Comment: Vinod Bhavnani: could you elaborate on your response please?

Comment: Ok here it goes. You said "My first thought was to put a function outside of the PHP loop which hides all divs of class modal, but then that would be triggered each time the user clicked anywhere on the page, and therefore, would also hide the div when the user clicks on the link to open it." But you can actually do this inside a condition by running the function only if modal-content class count is greater than 0

Comment: Ah, and then hide all divs of that class? If that is what you mean, I would be really grateful if you could write a quick piece of code that shows me how you would do that.... I'm quite stuck here.

Comment: Ok give me a minute

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the count of open modal windows in this function:

```
// Close modal onclick outside the modal
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if(event.target.className != "open_Modal"){
        var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")
        var modal_count = 0; //Initialize Count
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
           if(arr[i].style.display == "block"){
              modal_count++; //Increase count for all modals with display: block
           }
        }
       if (modal_count > 0) //Run function only if modal_count is more than 0
       { 
         for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
           arr[i].style.display = "none"; 
           modal_count = 0; //Reset modal_count to 0 again
         }
       }
    }   
}
```

This way your function will not run unless there is a minimum of 1 modal window open on your page.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I still see a problem here... the document.getElementsByClassName("modal") will always return a positive value, because those divs are always present, just hidden. Therefore, window.onclick will still apply to them whether they are visible or not (right?).

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This is precisely the kind of thing that I was thinking of. But for some reason I cannot figure out, it is still not working.

Comment: The page is online here: http://www.s-on.ch -- the popups are associated with the addresses (next to 'WHERE:') for each entry. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Can you debug this on your browser console? Open a modal and then click outside. Put a break point on the if (model_count > 0) and tell me what count are you getting

Comment: Sorry edited my answer again. You have to reset modal_count to 0 again after hiding them

Comment: Do everything inside the click function

Comment: I did a debug (loading the window, not clicking outside of it; the breakpoint kicks in when I open the popup). I get the following: i:4, modal_count: 1

Comment: Shouldn't 'modal_count' remain as 0 until I click outside the window?

Comment: No modal_count = 1 when 1 modal window is open

Comment: When you click outside, the modal should hide and modal_count should be reset to 0

Comment: Ah, but then we get back to the original problem, don't we? Namely, that by clicking the link, we set modal_count to 1 immediately, and the same click then calls the if (modal_count > 0) ... etc.?

Comment: It seems to me that it is necessary to count the click functions, so that the arr[i].style.display = "none"; is only called on the second one? Just a thought.

Comment: Ok then in the function you need to check if the event target is the link. If it is, then don't run the function. You have the event parameter right? Just check if event.target = the link

Comment: Ahh, great idea! The link is from a <SPAN> with a specific id (i.e. 'open_popup_N') -- therefore I would either have to make all links part of a class, or repeat the javascript for each instance, right?

Comment: Give each link a class of open_popup perhaps. Then onclick check if the event.taget has that class. If it does, then don't run the function :)

Comment: I hate to press you after all the help you've given me, but could you please show me how you would do that? My attempts just now did not work.

Comment: if(event.target.className) != "open_modal" then run the function :)

Comment: try to console out the event.target. You can see all available options. Then you an use any one you like to set the condition. I would suggest using className or classlist array

Comment: Argh, still not working for me! I'm clearly out of my depth on this one :-) Could you please add that to the code you wrote already, then I will leave you in peace! :-)

Comment: Ok just a minute

Comment: If it doesn't work , just try to play around with the code logic. It's just a little bit here and there. I can't give you a perfect code because I don't have the application running with me locally. And much can't be done on browser console. So ultimately you will have to figure out the little delta in the logic :) But I gave you the overall explanation of how you can do it. Hope I was of help. If yes, please mark my answer as correct :) That would help me.

Comment: WORKING! It was because of a stupid mismatch in the div name :-/ It's amazing how getting frustrated with code can cause you to make foolish mistakes. Thanks fo much for your help! I really appreciate it very much.